# While porting a windows application to web, is it better to stick to conventional web technologies or adoping RIA is wise?

Tags: silverlight, extjs, browser-plugin

The web based application I am working on currently is a port from a windows application. This application is very data intensive. There are scores of modules and each of these modules have number of forms (data entry screens) and reports whereas the forms have many many fields and likewise the reports.

I have been trying to identify the most suitable architecture for the presentation tier. There are many functions that are not very easily portable, for example printing (this too is very complex). For most of the others, I am planning to us "Ext JS" library which looks like capable of handling about 70% of complexity out of the box while for the remaining I would be custom coding or extending Ext JS.

Having said that (sorry for being so descriptive), I wonder, if this is an Intranet application, why not port the entire application to SilverLight? While I am good at .Net, I'm somewhat alien to SilverLight. Considering I know my target audience and that the software will be used per seat license, would it be better to ride on SilverLight or is it better to stick to conventional web (XHTML, JS, CSS, etc)? Further, I have to support multiple devices in future and considering that SilverLight plug-ins for many devices are yet not out, would it be a risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, if you are developing a web application, then yes, develop it as an RIA.

The choice of technology is up to you. I prefer jQuery and have never used ExtJS. But I've taken a look at it, and if your aplication is a port of a windows application and has a lot of conventional UI elements like forms, input boxes, toolbars, menus, button etc, then go for ExtJS.

As for some controls that are not available in ExtJS, you can easily extend ExtJS.

Regarding .NET: ExtJS is completely server-technology agnostic, so you can develop your application in .NET and still use an ExtJS UI. In fact, I would prefer to do such an implementation.

Regarding Silverlight: I am slightly against using silverlight, primarily because it requires a plugin to be installed that is not available on all platforms. But since your application is an intranet application, your user base will be in your control. But you should make sure that any future decision regarding the workstation platform will not affect your application's working.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Whether to use Silverlight over HTML/JS etc. in this case would depend on 2 key factors.

- What are you familar with already
- What type and range of devices you need to reach.

If you are already comfortable with HTML + ExtJS then that has to be huge pro in its favor.

The range of devices that Silverlight is possibly going to be available (Windows Phone 7 for example as well as Moonlight, I've even heard that there may be port for Andriod and Symbian) is growing.  However its really early days for that and not all may materialise in a form useful to you.

Having said that it should be acknowledged that a UI designed for use on desktop does not work well on a small device.  Hence you would need to develop some task specific UI for other devices regardless of the technology you use.  This in turn means that there is no reason for you to try to stick with single technology for all devices.

I think you should look very carefully into WCF, REST and [OData](http://www.odata.org) first.  Good layering of the application into useful models using these would more easily enable the use of a variety of front-end technologies for the client.

If you are into .NET and other Microsoft tech then you should seriously consider using JQuery and ASP.NET MVC as another potential front end technology.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to ponder the inconveniences of a solution based solely in Silverlight. Like Flash it needs a plugin to be installed in every station, so it loses some of the premises of web applications (run everywhere with the only requirement of a browser). Besides although Silverlight has taken great advances, it is not yet a widely supported standard, and it is in control of a company who later may decide for you in very important matters regarding the platform you use, and made it outdated or useless (in the worst case).

Ext JS is a great library developed entirely in Javascript, so you can touch anything that suits your needs. If the Windows applications you are basing on is well-layered, then your work may not be that hard.

If you are an asp.net developer you could take a look on asp.net mvc, a great set of tools that implements MVC pattern to web applications using the same old C# or VB. Besides the developers behind asp.net mvc, have taken a lot of work to make it suitable to work with javascript libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Happy coding!!!